# Decrementing size_t on the right hand of assignment

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, size-t

Why is `idx1` -1 in this case?

```
long long idx = (size_t)0 - 1;
```

`cout << (size_t)0 - 1;`
This prints `ULLONG_MAX`

`cout << idx;` This prints -1

What would change if `idx` was integer instead?

Comment: On the Visual Studio 2019 C++ compiler, I get UINT_MAX for both, which I would suggest is the correct behaviour.

Comment: Interesting, gcc disagrees: https://ideone.com/XGptUJ

Comment: Yeah. That's odd.

Comment: What does `long long idx = {(size_t)0 - 1};` do on gcc?

Comment: It doesn't compile, you can easily fork the code on ideone and check for yourself: https://ideone.com/6PIoZ3

Comment: The difference come down to the fact that `sizeof(size_t)` is 4 bytes on VS and 8 bytes on gcc.

Comment: Ah, I see, it works as expected for __int128: https://ideone.com/O3i878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
cout << (size_t)0 - 1;
```

the type of the expression `(size_t)0 - 1` is the unsigned integer type `size_t` due to the usual arithmetic conversions. Because it can't be negative, it has the value `ULLONG_MAX` (it seems that in the used system the type size_t is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long long int`).

In this declaration

```
long long idx = (size_t)0 - 1;
```

the initializer is converted to the signed type long long int that is to the type of the declared object. The UNIT_MAX value cannot fit into a *signed* long long, so it gives -1.

As the width of the type `size_t` in the used system is the same as the width of the type long long int. So the internal representation of the initializer of the type size_t is interpreted as a value of the type long long  That is the most significant bit of the unsigned initializer is considered as the sign bit.int.

Comment: Surely the expression `(size_t)0 - 1` is unsigned regardless of type it's being assigned into.

Comment: @JasperKent During the initialization the expression is converted to a value of  the type of the initialized object.

Comment: Could you point to some rules in the documentation? I have no idea how this should work.

Comment: @JKS Read the C standard about the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: But in the case of `long long idx = (size_t)0 - 1;` it's doing a bitwise conversion, not an arithmetic conversion.

Comment: @JasperKent I did not say that in this case there is used the usual arithmetic conversion. I said that the expression is interpreted as a value of the type long long int.

Comment: Okay, but why isn't it evaluated first and then converted?

Comment: @JKS Before evaluation of the expression the compiler has to determine the common type of operands that is the result type of the expression. In such a case it uses the usual arithmetic conversions. The rank of the type size_t is greater than the rank of the constant -1 that has the type int. So the common type of th expression will be size_t.

Comment: I've edited @VladfromMoscow's answer to clarify matters.

Comment: I see, I made a mistake thinking that printed value is 32-bit UINT_MAX when in fact it was 64-bit ULLONG_MAX